# Start smartgit with another java version

Tags: java, smartgit

I tried to start smartgit 6.5 on my Ubuntu 14.10 32bit with another java version.

in the file `/usr/share/smartgit/bin/smartgit.sh` it sais:

```
# To specify an alternative Java Runtime Environment, set the environment
# variable SMARTGIT_JAVA_HOME or add a
#
# jre=/path/to/jre
#
# line to smartgit.vmoptions (see below).
#
# To specify additional VM options, add them to smargit.vmoptions
# or ~/.smartgit/smartgit.vmoptions files.
```

[Here](http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG071/VM+options) I found an answer how to edit the file:

```
gedit ~/.smartgit/smartgit.vmoptions
```

So I entered just:

```
jre=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java
```

I thought, this should change the used java version in smartgit (visible in the menu Help->Information)

But it doesn't! It's still on `1.7.0_72-b14 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre)`

How does this file have to look like to use another Java engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution: When you start smartgit on the console:

```
smartgit-start
```

you get a warning:

> Warning: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java/bin/java does not exist

there is a double `/bin/java` in that path, so you only have to enter the path to the `bin` folder:

```
gedit ~/.smartgit/smartgit.vmoptions
```

And enter just:

```
jre=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

This starts smartgit with that version

---

Since now you always have to start smartgit on the console now, a smaller file would be handy: create a file `/usr/local/sbin/smg`

```
cd /tmp;
nohup /usr/share/smartgit/bin/smartgit.sh &
```

and give it executable rights:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/smg
```

now you can start smartgit anywhere with just

```
smg
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile ...elder versions still require JRE 8:

```
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Which result in these `smartgit.vmoptions`:

```
jre=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Comment: Some elder versions don't start at all die to end of supported time. Setting back the system time in your laptop during start still works though ;)

Comment: Maybe for very old versions, mine was out of support for 5 years; removed JDK 8 and it broke. Indeed would need a new license for a version supporting the current JDK 11.